# Android: How to obtain an url of a location using Latitude & Longitude?

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi I am trying create an app in android which can obtain the current location and send current location's url to my friend through `SMS`.

I created an app to get current location's `longitude & latitude` and send it to my friend through`SMS`, I would like to know how to obtain current location's url, so that when they click on the message the map opens in google maps.

I would like to know how to obtain url using latitude & longitude or in any other way in android.

Comment: thanks mate, i tried to search but couldn't get.:-)

Comment: "android sms open map" in google first link FYI

Comment: Got it, Thank you.:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
http://maps.google.com/?q=<lat>,<lng>
```

Use the above format, pass your values of lat and lng to the above URL format.